# PHP external variable from react

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, reactjs

I know how to send data from PHP to the react component but how do i send an id selected in a menu from the react component to the PHP file?

```
$.ajax({url: '/file.php', type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
      success: response => {
        console.log(response)
      }});
```

And in the PHP file:

```
$testid= //how do i send a variable here
$results = $db->statement("SELECT * FROM tablename where id='testid");

echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: That's not a react component it looks like a jQuery ajax call. What does your component look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'name': 'john'
    },
    success: response => {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

PHP file:

```
$testid= $_POST["name"];
$results = $db->statement("SELECT * FROM tablename where id = $testid");

echo json_encode($results);
```

> **WARNING: YOUR SQL QUERY WILL BE VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION. [LEARN HOW TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the id via JavaScript

```
$.ajax({url: '/file.php', data : {userId : ?} , type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
           success: response => {
              console.log(response)
           }});
```

and then you need to get the value from `$_POST` and concat it with the query

```
$testid= $_POST["userId"];
$results = $db->statement("SELECT * FROM tablename where id = " . $testid);
```

but this could cause ***SQL Injection***